# HEVC/H.265 GPU HW decoding and output to different card

Tags: gpu, h.265, kaby-lake

I use a Kaby Lake CPU (i7-7700) to enable HEVC hardware decoding. Besides the embedded GPU I also have a NVIDIA GTX 970. My display is hooked up to the NVIDIA card. I'm trying to play the samples from http://jell.yfish.us/ but I have a sub par solution for my Windows 10 system that I'm trying to solve.

On Linux I can do

```
mpv --hwdec=vaapi-copy jellyfish-400-mbps-4k-uhd-hevc-10bit.mkv
```

This works really well. All decoding is happening on the Kaby Lake (well, the GPU on the processor) and actually the video comes out of the NVIDIA card. Super, my CPU utilization is extremely low and the picture is awesome!

On Windows I haven't found a media player that would support the same configuration. Decoding happening on the CPU GPU and video output from the NVIDIA card.

My current workaround is to just change my cable from NVIDIA HDMI to the motherboard HDMI and the samples run fine. It seems all players use the GPU that the display is hooked up to. I have tried with Windows Media Player, Movies & TV app, VLC and MPC-HC.

Any idea how on Windows I can achieve the same experience as on Linux? I want to use the NVIDIA card output for my display but HEVC to be decoded on the GPU on the CPU.

Comment: Pingback: [How to force Chrome to use integrated GPU for decoding?](https://superuser.com/q/1319250/)